# Declare Generic Type as Callable

Tags: generics, swift

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Foo<BlockT> {
    var blocks = Array<BlockT>
    func callTheBlocks() {
        for block in blocks {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

However, this raises

> Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type 'BlockT'.

How do I declare `BlockT` to be callable, or to be of "function type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blocks/closures without arguments and without return value you can use
the built-in

```
typealias dispatch_block_t = () -> Void
```

Example:

```
class Foo {
    var blocks = Array<dispatch_block_t>()
    func callTheBlocks() {
        for block in blocks {
            block()
        }
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.blocks.append { println("Foo") }
foo.blocks.append { println("Bar") }
foo.callTheBlocks()
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize at first that I did not actually need generic signatures for my blocks, so declaring the blocks to be `() -> Void` should actually be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `T` is the return type of the block, which can be `Void` if it doesn't return anything

```
class Foo<T> {
    var blocks = Array<(Void -> T)>()
    func callTheBlocks() {
        for block in blocks {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```